# Is it correct to say "They watch stories on YouTube"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

My children watch some videos about stories such as "**Little Red Riding Hood" or "Cinderella**" on YouTube.

Is it correct to say "**They watch stories on YouTube**"?

Comment: You can read stories or listen to recordings of them or someone telling them. Does that answer your question? I would definitely not say: watch stories on YouTube. Watch videos of children's stories.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preposition "on" is fine, and I guess "watch stories" would be understood.

However, more commonly we say "watch **videos** on X" and "**read** stories on Y".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely.

You are using the correct preposition: ***on***.

> on television
>
> on the Internet
>
> etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's totally correct.
We use on to indicate using a device or machine. He is on the phone right now. Ex. He has been on the computer since morning.
Likwise, we can use on for all social media platforms.
Ex. I posted a new video on Facbook yesterday.
Ex. I've seen the news on twitter.